# Unique Identifier in Obligation Cordapp

Tags: corda

I have replicated the Obligation Cordapp Transfer functionality and i am struck with the linearId of Unique Identifier. I have successfully exercised the Issue Cordapp and for transfer of Obligation, i have provided the flow command with linearId of generated Obligation. The parameter which i am passing through linearId is interpreted as the **External id** [argument in UniqueIdentifier] instead of **id** and so it is unable to find the Obligation to transfer.

Here are reference for issue.

The generated id for the Obligation created is

**linearId : externalId: null

**id: "4799c549-8c2b-401f-90dd-1dc115fbcfba"**

```
Thu Mar 29 18:41:02 IST 2018>>> flow start TransferObligation$Initiator newLender: "O=PartyC,L=Paris,C=FR",anonymous: false,linearId: "4799c549-8c2b-401f-90dd-1dc115fbcfba
```

The passed argument, linearId has to take as id [argument in UniqueIdentifier and is randomly generated if external id is not equal to null] as per Obligation Cordapp and has to do required transfer functionality. Instead it is taking linearId passed as externalId [argument in UniqueIdentifier] and so total linearId becoming **externalId_id**.

```
>Linear Id parameter is:4799c549-8c2b-401f-90dd-1dc115fbcfba_ace60f85-b360-4cf7b198-4d3d471f9d63
>Obtaining IOU from vault.
>States Size:0
```

Observing that ace60f85-b360-4cf7b198-4d3d471f9d63 is appended as id which is randomly generated and unable to find the Obligation generated.

How corda will interpret linearId passed? as externalId/Id as default?
In Obligation Cordapp it demonstrated in samples took as Id and required job is done.But the cordapp which i am exercising takes the passed parameter as externalId.

Or any changes has to be done in code level to take the linearId parameter as id?

Edit 1:
We are developing the code in java The transfer obligation for reference.Although it is just a replicate.Please have a look at it

```
  package com.example.flow;

import co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Suspendable;
import com.example.contract.ActivityContract;
import com.example.state.Activity;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import net.corda.confidential.IdentitySyncFlow;
import net.corda.confidential.SwapIdentitiesFlow;
import net.corda.core.contracts.Command;
import net.corda.core.contracts.StateAndRef;
import net.corda.core.contracts.UniqueIdentifier;
import net.corda.core.flows.*;
import net.corda.core.identity.AbstractParty;
import net.corda.core.identity.AnonymousParty;
import net.corda.core.identity.Party;
import net.corda.core.transactions.SignedTransaction;
import net.corda.core.transactions.TransactionBuilder;
import net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker;
import net.corda.core.utilities.ProgressTracker.Step;


import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.util.*;

import static com.example.contract.ActivityContract.Activity_Contract_ID;

public class ActivityTransferFlow {

    @StartableByRPC
    @InitiatingFlow
    public static class Initiator extends ActivityBaseFlow{


    public final UniqueIdentifier linearId;
    public final Party newLender;
    public final Boolean anonymous;

    private final Step INITIATION = new Step("Obtaining IOU from vault.");
    private final Step BUILDING = new Step("Building and Verifying Transaction");
    private final Step SIGNING = new Step("Signing gathered transaction");
    private final Step SYNCING = new Step("Syncing gathered identities "){

        @Override
        public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
            return IdentitySyncFlow.Send.Companion.tracker();
        }
    };

    private final Step GATHERING = new Step("Gathering counterparty signatures"){

        @Override
        public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
            return CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker();
        }
    };

    private final Step FINALISING = new Step("Finalising transaction"){

        @Override
        public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
            return FinalityFlow.Companion.tracker();
        }
    };

       private final ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker(
               INITIATION,
               BUILDING,
               SIGNING,
               SYNCING,
               GATHERING,
               FINALISING
       );

        public Initiator(UniqueIdentifier linearId, Party newLender, Boolean anonymous) {

            this.linearId = linearId;
            this.newLender = newLender;
            this.anonymous = anonymous;
        }

        @Override
        public ProgressTracker getProgressTracker() {
            return progressTracker;
        }

        @Suspendable
        @Override
        public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {

            // step1:Retrieve Activity specified by linear id from the vault
            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(INITIATION);

            final StateAndRef<Activity> activityToTransfer= getObligationByLinearId(linearId);
            }



            final Activity inputActivity=activityToTransfer.getState().getData();

            //step2:This flow can only be initiated by current recipient
            final AbstractParty lenderIdentity =getLenderIdentity(inputActivity);

            //step3:Abort if the borrower started this flow
            if(!getOurIdentity().equals(lenderIdentity))
            {
             throw new IllegalStateException("Activity transfer can only be initiated by the lender.");
            }

            //step4:Creating the new obligation state reflecting a new lender
             progressTracker.setCurrentStep(BUILDING);
             final Activity transferredActivity =createOutputActivity(inputActivity);

             //step4:Create transfer command
             final List<PublicKey> signerKeys = new ImmutableList.Builder<PublicKey>()
                     .addAll(inputActivity.getParticipantKeys())
                     .add(transferredActivity.getLender().getOwningKey()).build();

            final Command transferCommand = new Command<>(new ActivityContract.Commands.ActivityTransfer(), signerKeys);

            //step5:Create a transaction builder and then add states and commands.
            final TransactionBuilder builder = new TransactionBuilder(getNotary())
                    .addInputState(activityToTransfer)
                    .addOutputState(transferredActivity, Activity_Contract_ID)
                    .addCommand(transferCommand);

            //step6:Verify and sign the transaction
            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(SIGNING);
            builder.verify(getServiceHub());
            final SignedTransaction ptx=getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(builder, inputActivity.getLender().getOwningKey());

            //step7:Getting party object from the borrower
            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(SYNCING);
            final Party borrower=getBorrowerIdentity(inputActivity);

            //step8:Send any keys or certificates so the signers can verify each other identity
            Set<FlowSession> sessions=new HashSet<>();
            Set<Party> parties= ImmutableSet.of(borrower,newLender);
            for (Party party:parties) {

                  sessions.add(initiateFlow(party));

            }
            subFlow(new IdentitySyncFlow.Send(sessions,ptx.getTx(),SYNCING.childProgressTracker()));

            //step9:Gathering signatures from the borrower and the new lender
             progressTracker.setCurrentStep(GATHERING);
             final SignedTransaction stx=subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(
                     ptx,
                     sessions,
                     ImmutableList.of(inputActivity.getLender().getOwningKey()),
                     GATHERING.childProgressTracker()
             ));

            //Step10:Notarise and record the transaction into vault and broadcast the transaction

            progressTracker.setCurrentStep(FINALISING);
            return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(stx,ImmutableSet.of(getOurIdentity())));
        }

        @Suspendable
        private AbstractParty getLenderIdentity(Activity inputObligation) {
            if (inputObligation.getLender() instanceof AnonymousParty) {
                return resolveIdentity(inputObligation.getLender());
            } else {
                return inputObligation.getLender();
            }
        }

        @Suspendable
        private Activity createOutputActivity(Activity inputActivity) throws FlowException {
            if (anonymous) {
                final HashMap<Party, AnonymousParty> txKeys = subFlow(new SwapIdentitiesFlow(newLender));
                if (!txKeys.containsKey(newLender)) {
                    throw new FlowException("Couldn't get lender's conf. identity.");
                }
                final AnonymousParty anonymousLender = txKeys.get(newLender);
                return inputActivity.withNewLender(anonymousLender);
            } else {
                return inputActivity.withNewLender(newLender);
            }
        }

        @Suspendable
        private Party getBorrowerIdentity(Activity inputActivity) {
            if (inputActivity.getBorrower() instanceof AnonymousParty) {
                return resolveIdentity(inputActivity.getBorrower());
            } else {
                return (Party) inputActivity.getBorrower();
            }
        }
    }



    @InitiatedBy(Initiator.class)
    public static class Responder extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
        private final FlowSession otherFlow;

        public Responder(FlowSession otherFlow) {
            this.otherFlow = otherFlow;
        }

        @Suspendable
        @Override
        public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
            subFlow(new IdentitySyncFlow.Receive(otherFlow));
            SignedTransaction stx = subFlow(new ActivityBaseFlow.SignTxFlowNoChecking(otherFlow, SignTransactionFlow.Companion.tracker()));
            return waitForLedgerCommit(stx.getId());
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit 2:**
The getObligationByLinearId method in ActivityBaseFlow
and the command we use is

> flow start ActivityTransferFlow$Initiator linearId: d21827b7-e4be-4874-9383-e9f339d7c9ea,newLender: "O=PartyC,L=Paris,C=FR",anonymous: false

```
StateAndRef<Activity> getObligationByLinearId(UniqueIdentifier linearId) throws FlowException {
    System.out.println("Linear Id parameter is:"+linearId);
    QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(
            null,
            ImmutableList.of(linearId),
            Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED,
            null);
    List<StateAndRef<Activity>> obligations = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(Activity.class, queryCriteria).getStates();
    if (obligations.size() != 1) {
        System.out.println("Linear Id 1:"+linearId);
        throw new FlowException(String.format("Obligation with id %s not found.", linearId));
    }
    //System.out.println("Linear Id 2:"+linearId);
    return obligations.get(0);
}
```

Comment: Did you parse your id to UniqueIdentifier? i.e ` val linearId = UniqueIdentifier.fromString(myInputString)`

Comment: we have not utilized fromString function, However even that is not used in Reference too..I have attached my transferActivity,please have a look @Adrian

Comment: Need to see how getObligationByLinearId is implemented. Also need to see the entry point where you pass the linearId to this flow. Assuming its on the API, you need to use fromString. per the link 
https://github.com/roger3cev/obligation-cordapp/blob/67a4e9e67e502b9305ea9b0a0692665ae554506e/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/obligation/ObligationApi.kt#L124

Comment: As we are testing the functionality and flow, we are passing the arguments and starting the required flows through commands itself.I have mentioned the command we use to start flow. I have attached the required code

Comment: Makes sense, since it takes the string in as a constructor for the externalId. Changing your flow to accepts a string, then parse it using fromString will solve you problem as it will construct the id in UniqueIdentifier using that. Not sure which reference you're using to say it didn't require it? Obligation Cordapp is using the API to parse it, don't think the documentation said anything about using command line flow start.

Comment: Thank you very much @Adrian I have overlooked the companion method fromString and now the issue is resolved. Thanks a lot for help. We have prepared the commands as per the first tutorial of CordApp and now its resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UniqueIdentifier` constructor is taking the string input from `flow start` as the `externalId`.

Change your flow to accept a string instead and manually parse it using `UniqueIdentifier.fromString(inputString)`. i.e

```
public Initiator(String inputString, Party newLender, Boolean anonymous) {

            this.linearId = UniqueIdentifier.fromString(inputString);
            this.newLender = newLender;
            this.anonymous = anonymous;
        }
```